# JS Scroller doesnt scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys we have our frontpage here: http://wp.partyloo.com/

And I added a scroller down arrow to it to scroll down on the next section just below it.

I got the following HTML:

```
   <a id="scroll" href="#second"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:54px; color: #fff; text-align: center; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And here's the JS that i place:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 600);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Right now when you click on the arrow it doesn't scroll down smoothly. When you click on it just automatically take you to the next div/section.

How can I put some smooth animation so that it scrolls down smooth and easingly?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
a {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 2s;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?